# How does finder figure this directory is 6MB?

Tags: finder

[image]

The directory says it's 6 MB, but there's about 10 160-byte files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your directory may contain hidden files. OS X uses hidden files (prefixed with a `.` dot when using `ls -la`) to store meta information on the folder (position and sorting of the icons for example). To have a precise breakup of your directory size use

```
du -h /Users/azz0r/Sites/Personal/php-rest-api
```

in Terminal. You can limit the depth of displayed files with the `-d DEPTH` option.

To see the hidden files recursively from a directory use the `ls -laR` command.

To show hidden file directly in the finder, you could also follow this post [Show hidden files Mac OS X 10.7 Lion and 10.8 Mountain Lion](http://www.mikesel.info/show-hidden-files-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/).